# How can we stop caching in magento

Tags: magento

In magento, there is a option is available by which we can stop caching.  [image]

my question is why cache files are created,if we disabled the cache? and my second question Is there any way by which we can prevent creation of cache files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things cached in Magento even if the cache is turned off.
Here are some examples.

- the language select in admin footer: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Footer::getLanguageSelect`
- the admin notification config field: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Notification::_getElementHtml`
- admin notification last feed update: `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed::getLastUpdate`
- last cron execution: `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::generate`
- and specially the table schemas. this is done by ZF itself
- ...and there are others.

The solution for this would be to override the methods `Mage_Core_Model_App::saveCache` and `Mage_Core_Model_App::loadCache` to not save anything or not return anything when you want it disabled completely. But I don't think this is a good idea because it might affect some parts of the application.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my request. However I have a doubt. Why Magento set above sections always cached ? Is there any problem if these blocks get uncached ?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. Most probably it will work with them uncached.

Comment: hmm. sounds weired. There must be some reason. Let us hope the reason will disclose soon :)

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that the cache has been completely cleared, click the Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage buttons in the upper right hand side of Cache Storage Management menu.